# Trying to pass multiple JSON data to Highcharts without success

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, highcharts

I'm trying to create some Highstock charts (Highcharts) using sampled data but all I get when I run it its a blank page.

This is my php code:

```
<?php
header("Content-type: text/json");
$horas_muertas = array(array(1296518400000,4),array(1296604800000,2),array(1296691200000,3),array(1296777600000,3));
$horas_trabajadas = array(array(1296518400000,2),array(1296604800000,3),array(1296691200000,4),array(1296777600000,5));
$datos = array(json_encode($horas_muertas),json_encode($horas_trabajadas));    


$datosj = json_encode($datos);

echo $datosj[0];

?>
```

As you can see I tried accesing the first location of the JSON, which returned this so I'm sure something's wrong there:

```
[
```

But when I use this code for the chart(I removed non-relevant code):

```
function requestData() {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'data.php',
                datatype: 'json',
                success: function(data) {                       
                    //alert(data);                      
                    chart.series[0].setData(data[0]);
                    chart.series[1].setData(data[1]);
                },
                cache: false
            });
        }
$(function() {
var chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({

                chart: {
                    renderTo: 'container',
                    type: 'column',
                        events: {
                        load: requestData
                    }
                },
                series: [{
                    name: 'Horas Prendidas',
                data: []},
                {
                    name: 'Horas Trabajadas',
                data: []}]
            });
        });​
```

All I get is a blank page,when I at least should get a chart without any data on it, any ideas on how to solve this? Help is much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `chart.series[0].addPoint(data[0]);` instead of `chart.series[0].setData(data[0]);`

Comment: Thanks! Still, I'm not getting anything on my page, I'm guessing it's because datos[0] its not returning the first JSON, is there any way access the first part like an array?

Comment: Well, if ajax call is returning JSON than you can directly try chart.series[0].setData(data);. And if that does not work try to find if there is a syntax error on the page for javascript. Most times the chart page is blank when there is a syntax error in javascript.

Comment: Strangely enough, somehow one of those non-printable characters in unicode got into my code, I only noticed it when looking into the code with an hex editor, thanks anyways!